# Rails 5 Active Admin use JQuery to show/hide field in form after dropdown selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

**EDIT: I used Leo answer and edited the code a little, update code below**

I have course model which has many segments. Segment is Video or Quiz, and Quiz has many questions.
I have form which contain dropdown which named type who contain Video or Quiz. I want that when I select Video, immediately another field will show, and when I select Quiz others fields will show. I wrote what I want to get and how the form acts, but I just don't know how active admin works with JQuery or what JQuery I need to write in order for this to work (and where to write it).

**This is my form (Updated):**

```js
form do |f|
  tabs do
    tab 'Basic Info' do
      f.inputs "Course details" do
        f.input :title
        f.input :author
      end
    end

    tab 'Content' do
      f.inputs "Segments" do
        f.has_many :segments, heading: false, allow_destroy: true do |s|
          s.input :unit_id
          s.input :unit_title
          s.input :name
          s.input :type, as: :select, collection: Segment.type?, class: 'select-type'

          # I want that if Video selected than it'll open string field
          s.inputs 'video', class: 'video-tab', style: "display: #{s.object.type == 'Video' ? 'block' : 'none'}" do
              s.input :data, :as => :string
          end

          # I want that if Quiz selected than it'll open options for questions and answers
          s.inputs 'quiz', class: 'quiz-tab', style: "display: #{s.object.type == 'Quiz' ? 'block' : 'none'}" do
            s.has_many :questions, heading:"Question", allow_destroy: true do |q|
              q.input :question
              q.input :answer1
              q.input :answer2
              q.input :answer3
              q.input :answer4
              q.input :correct
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
    f.actions
end
```

**active_admin.js (thanks to Leo for the help)**

```js
//= require active_admin/base
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.select-type').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'Video') {
      $('.video-tab').css('display', 'block');
      $('.quize-tab').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
      $('.video-tab').css('display', 'none');
      $('.quize-tab').css('display', 'block');
    }
  })
})
```

Thanks beforehand

EDIT: I'll add the models too:

**course model**

```js
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title ,presence: true
  validates :author ,presence: true

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions

  has_many :segments, inverse_of: :course, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**segment model**

```js
class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :course_id ,presence: true
  validates :name ,presence: true
  validates :type ,presence: true
  validates :data ,presence: true

  belongs_to :course, inverse_of: :segments
  has_many :completed_segments
  validates_presence_of :course

  def self.type
    descendants.map{ |t| t.to_s }.sort
  end

  def self.type?
    return self.type
  end

end
```

**video model**

```js
class Video < Segment
  validates :name ,presence: true

  belongs_to :course

end
```

**quiz model**

```js
class Quiz < Segment
  validates :name ,presence: true

  has_many :questions
  belongs_to :course
  validates_presence_of :quiz
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**question model**

```js
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  validates :question ,presence: true
  validates :answer1 ,presence: true
  validates :answer2 ,presence: true
  validates :answer3 ,presence: true
  validates :answer4 ,presence: true
  validates :correct ,presence: true

  belongs_to :quiz

end
```

Comment: you can override form with your custom form (partial), where you can design as per your requirement and Jquery to show / hide some contents for more details read https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#partials

Comment: why can't I do it here? and I still need to write the JQuery in the javascript files no? The only thing I don't know is how to write the JQuery. I'm using Angular so I'm not so good with JQuery and I don't know how JQuery and actvie admin works

Comment: your code should work for "edit" form, but in "new" form you won't get `s.object.type`, apart from that if you want to use Jquery you can simply use like `s.input :type, as: :select, collection: Segment.all, :input_html => {:onchange => 'your Jquery code / function'}`

Comment: How do I get it to work also on new?